# UITableView is loading late and stuck

Tags: ios, swrevealviewcontroller

I am Using third party library for making right drawer [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController)

When I register my NIB file in `ViewDidLoad()` method it take time(stuck) to open the Drawer and I see the different Variation with respect to the device Processing speed .

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
//    // Custom initialization
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:headerCellIdentifier bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:headerCellIdentifier];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:rowCellIdentifier bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:rowCellIdentifier];

}
```